# python - password expiry

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I am trying to add a password expiry on to my web application. The goal is for the user to change their password every 30 days with a notification of how many days are left before they have to change their password. I am trying to calculate the amount of days left using :

```
enter code here

 import datetime
 today = datetime.date.today()

 expire = 30
 day = today.strftime(' %d ')
 daysLeft = (expire - day)

 print today.strftime('you have '+ daysLeft +' days to change your password')
```

but am having issues because I am trying to use an integer and a string in the one sum. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the today.strftime( ) call, this way you explicitely convert it into a string. Do the math first and then use it to display in human format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to convert a string to an integer, use this syntax :

`daysLeft = (expire - int(day))`

if you want to convert an integer to a string, you can use this syntax :

`today.strftime('you have '+ str(daysLeft) +' days to change your password')`

But as André Schild said in the comments, you probably don't want to do it this way. You could just print your message without calling strftime, if the information you want to be displayed is on the days remaining only.